# Update Lookup field to connect to child object

Tags: trigger, lookup, update

I have a lookup field to a child object on the Account object i want to update with a record Id for a child object.

I want to compare the text value in either the Billing State/Province field (or if blank, the Billing Country field) on the Account record to the Name_*c field on the Locale*_c object, returning the record Id for the matching Locale record to update the lookup field on the Account object.

Comment: Jason - welcome to SFSE. I think you'll find you'll get more assistance here if you reword your question to be more explicit about the various SObjects and their schema relationship to each other. Is Locale__c a child of Account? And what object does the lookup field on Account refer to?  Is the use case a user interface question (VF) or a trigger question or something else -- when does the event/transaction occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a trigger.  Something like:

```
trigger Account_bi on Account (before insert)
{
    // map of accounts keyed by the locale search text
    Map<String, List<Account>> accsBySearchField=new Map<String, List<Account>>();

    // build the map - iterate the accounts and extract the state or country field
    for (Account acc : trigger.new)
    {
        String searchStr=acc.BillingState!=null?acc.BillingState:acc.BillingCountry;

        if (null!=searchStr)
        {
            // add the account to the list of those with the same search string - these will all be updated with the same locale lookup
            List<Account> accs=accsBySearchStr.get(searchStr);
            if (null==accs)
            {
                accs=new List<Account>();
                accsBySearchStr.put(searchStr, accs);
            }

            accs.add(acc);
        }
    }

    // pull back all locale objects where the name matches a search string
    List<Locale__c> locales=[select id, Name__c from Locale__c where Name__c IN :accsBySearchStr.keySet()];
    for (Locale__c locale : locales)
    {
        // get the account records matching the name of the locale and set the lookup
        List<Account> accs=accsBySearchStr.get(locale);
        if (null!=accs)
        {
            for (Account acc : accs)
            {
                acc.Locale__c=locale.id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```